# How would plasma-based lifeforms interact with physical matter?

Tags: science-based, life, senses, energy-beings

I believe that I had previously wrote about the possibility of **energy beings**, although it seems that them being made of neutrinos is right out. So I instead thought of them being made of plasma. Some sources indeed consider the possibility of **plasma-based lifeforms**, and that they were existent in the very early ages of the planet. Here are some details of this made by [David Darling](https://www.daviddarling.info/encyclopedia/P/plasma-based_life.html#:%7E:text=Plasma%2Dbased%20life%20is%20hypothetical,state%20of%20matter%2C%27%20plasma.&text=The%20researchers%20studied%20environmental%20conditions,to%20form%20in%20the%20atmosphere.).

I need not have this setting be so hard in scientific authenticity, and I imagine that they can not only have long lives, at least in hot areas like stars (*they would most likely dissipate quickly in current Earth-like conditions*), but can be macroscopic in nature, ranging from the size of insects, or even human bodies.

However, one part that I still want to keep the "hard science" is how these plasma lifeforms interact with physical matter. What type of senses do they have? How do they see, hear and touch physical matter? Can they even have these senses at all?

Answer (score 4):

Plasma is made by a "cloud" of atoms dissociated in electrons and charged nuclei.

I am sure it would be pretty aggressive on physical matter. During my PhD I used to clean sample surfaces with a plasma for this very reason. So, shaking hands with plasma-man is a no no!

In order to see, these hypothetical creatures would need to interact with electromagnetic radiation. In our eyes this usually means that photons excite some molecules, triggering the transmission of a signal to the brain. With some or all of the electrons stripped from the nuclei, which is the condition to have a plasma, such interaction would be impossible, so they would be blind. They might sense magnetic or electric fields, though, since those would affect the charged species in the plasma.

Acoustic waves might propagate into plasma of adequate density, therefore it might be that these beings can hear something around them.